# How to create custom level in log4net?

Tags: log4net

How to create a custom level in Log4Net like '*ERROR*', '*WARN*', '*INFO*'. eg. I want to create a level '*General*' and I want to use it as

```
logger.General("This is general log");
```

Answer (score 6):

I found solution.

```
private static readonly log4net.Core.Level GeneralLevel= new log4net.Core.Level(50000,"General");

log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging=true;
log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().LevelMap.Add(GeneralLevel);

General("This is Custom Log");

public void General(string message)
{
    Log.Logger.log(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType,GeneralLevel,message,null);
}
```